# Query to Select TOP based on Boolean column & timestamp

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The goal of this **sample** query is get distinct customer_names and top 1 most up-to-date dog_name for each customer_name. Selecting customer_name, dog_name, ts (null in dogname or ts column is ok in my real query.)

The query must prefer the following order and include only one 'dog' in the output:
select where main_dog = 1 else where main_dog = 0 else then return the main_dog null row.
The query should return the top row selecting using the order of main_dog_flag preference first then the most recent record.

## Note:

1. I am using MSSQL, and the [BIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) Datatype for simulating the real system. The real system has flag datatype but I couldn't get this sample to work.
2. Real system has null values in these similar fields, I am not at the level to understand.

## customer_reserves

| customer_name | reserve_active |
| --- | --- |
| 'bob' | 1 |
| 'rick' | 1 |
| 'ross' | 1 |
| 'ross' | 1 |
| 'hank' | 0 |

## dogs

| customer_name | main_dog_flag | dog_name | ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'bob' | 0 | 'clop' | 2016-11-23 12:45:37.333 |
| 'bob' | 1 | 'zlop' | 2016-10-23 12:45:37.333 |
| 'bob' | NULL | NULL | 2016-12-23 12:45:37.333 |
| 'rick' | NULL | 'frankie' | 2016-12-23 12:45:37.333 |
| 'rick' | NULL | 'fjord' | 2018-12-23 12:45:37.333 |
| 'ross' | 0 | 'leow' | 2016-12-23 12:45:37.333 |
| 'ross' | NULL | NULL | 2020-02-23 12:45:37.333 |

## Expected result set

| Name | Dog | ts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bob | zlop | 2016-10-23 12:45:37.3330000 |
| rick | fjord | 2018-12-23 12:45:37.3330000 |
| ross | leow | 2020-02-23 12:45:37.3330000 |
| hank | NULL | NULL |

This is expected because:

1. bob's dog 'zlop' has main_dog_flag = 1 even if it does not have the most recent ts
2. rick's dog 'fjord' has most recent ts
3. ross's dog 'leow' is returned because of our preference of order with regard to main_dog_flag, even if ts is older
4. hank has no dogs, but we still get a row for him :).

Using the included tables, I have tried the following query in T-SQL:

```sql
SELECT r.customer_name, d.dog_name, d.flag, d.ts
FROM #customer_reserves AS r

OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT TOP 1
        d.customer_name
        ,d.dog_name
        ,'flag' = d.main_dog_flag
        ,d.ts
    FROM #dogs AS d

    WHERE r.customer_name = d.customer_name
    ORDER BY d.ts DESC

)AS d
```

## My query result

Current query returns ts column information *correctly* but not according to rules of preferring 1st) dog_main_flag = 1, then 2nd) dog_main_flag = 0 else dog_main_flag IS null

| Customer_name | dog_name | flag | ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bob | NULL | NULL | 2016-12-23 12:45:37.3330000 |
| rick | fjord | NULL | 2018-12-23 12:45:37.3330000 |
| ross | NULL | NULL | 2020-02-23 12:45:37.3330000 |
| hank | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Here is some boiler plate in T-SQL (check timestamp compatibility, I used DATETIME2 for T-Sql) if it makes things easier:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #customer_reserves (
    customer_name VARCHAR(10), reserve_active BIT
)
CREATE TABLE #dogs (
    customer_name VARCHAR(10), main_dog_flag BIT, dog_name VARCHAR(10), ts DATETIME2 
)

INSERT INTO #customer_reserves (customer_name, reserve_active) VALUES ('bob', 1)
INSERT INTO #customer_reserves (customer_name, reserve_active) VALUES ('rick', 1)
INSERT INTO #customer_reserves (customer_name, reserve_active) VALUES ('ross', 1)
INSERT INTO #customer_reserves (customer_name, reserve_active) VALUES ('hank', 0)

INSERT INTO #dogs (customer_name, main_dog_flag, dog_name, ts) VALUES ('bob', 0 , 'clop',           '2016-11-23 12:45:37.333')
INSERT INTO #dogs (customer_name, main_dog_flag, dog_name, ts) VALUES ('bob', 1 , 'zlop',           '2016-10-23 12:45:37.333')
INSERT INTO #dogs (customer_name, main_dog_flag, dog_name, ts) VALUES ('bob', NULL , NULL,          '2016-12-23 12:45:37.333')

INSERT INTO #dogs (customer_name, main_dog_flag, dog_name, ts) VALUES ('rick', NULL , 'frankie',    '2016-12-23 12:45:37.333')
INSERT INTO #dogs (customer_name, main_dog_flag, dog_name, ts) VALUES ('rick', NULL , 'fjord',      '2018-12-23 12:45:37.333')

INSERT INTO #dogs (customer_name, main_dog_flag, dog_name, ts) VALUES ('ross', 0 , 'leow',          '2016-12-23 12:45:37.333')
INSERT INTO #dogs (customer_name, main_dog_flag, dog_name, ts) VALUES ('ross', NULL , NULL,         '2020-02-23 12:45:37.333')     

SELECT r.customer_name, d.dog_name, d.flag, d.ts
FROM #customer_reserves AS r
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1
        d.customer_name
        ,d.dog_name
        ,'flag' = d.main_dog_flag
        ,d.ts
    FROM #dogs AS d
    WHERE r.customer_name = d.customer_name
    ORDER BY d.ts DESC
)AS d

--WHERE
--    d.main_dog_flag = 1 OR d.main_dog_flag IS NULL /*this excludes non main dogs - ross's dog 'leow'*/

DROP TABLE #customer_reserves
DROP TABLE #dogs
```

Comment: as all have the same timestamp,how should we now what is the last or not

Comment: You just need to add `main_dog_flag` to your cross apply order by i.e. before timestamp.

Comment: I had to specify DESC twice to get the expected rows (MSSQL v2016) :  `ORDER BY d.main_dog_flag DESC, d.ts DESC`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with cte (customer_name, dog_name, flag, ts, rn) as 
(
  select 
    c.customer_name, dog_name, main_dog_flag, d.ts,
    row_number() over (partition by c.customer_name order by main_dog_flag, d.ts desc)
  from #customer_reserves c
  left outer join #dogs d on c.customer_name=d.customer_name
)
select top 1 with ties 
    customer_name, dog_name, flag, ts
from cte
where rn = 1
order by rn
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation in addition to a working query

Answer (score 0):

Hi OP: I believe there is a mistake in your writeup.  Expected output should have ross with leow but the date should be 2016 because main_dog_flag = 0.  The date you have comes from the main_dog_flag null, contradicting your requirement.

I could not think of a way to do this in one query, so a CTE it is.  I ran the code from @EvgenyM and it produces an incorrect result.  See image below.

```
--  Use order by row_number() partition to group, then the order by inside bubbles up what we need to the top of each row based on your requirements:
--  1.(why cast main_dog_flag to int and case statement desc) we cast to int so we can use that in ordering in the actual select statement to get the final order.  The CTE order by uses this to bubble up the records we need, by customer (partition by) to the top for each customer
--      note: the test for main_dog_flag is null is not really necessary but good practice to address all possibilites
--  2. (d.ts desc) if a customer does not have a main_dog_flag = 1 or 0, then take the most recent date

;with cte_unordered_output as
(
    select  top 1 with ties
            cr.customer_name,
            d.dog_name,
            d.ts,
            coalesce(cast(d.main_dog_flag as int), -1) as main_dog_flag
    from    @customer_reserves cr
                    left outer join
            @dogs d on
                        cr.customer_name = d.customer_name
    order by    ROW_NUMBER () over 
                (
                    partition by    cr.customer_name 
                    order by        main_dog_flag desc,
                                    d.ts desc
                )
)


select  u.customer_name,
        u.dog_name,
        u.ts
from    cte_unordered_output u
order by    u.main_dog_flag desc,
            case when dog_name is not null then 1 else 0 end desc
```

[output - I do not have enough reputation to inline image because I have 100k+ reputation people voting down my results to steer others to their answers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7Dra.jpg)

[@EvgenyM result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLIuT.jpg)